# глагол + "в результате"/"в результате чего" + деепричастие + точка. Корректна ли такая конструкция?

Tags: глаголы, деепричастия

Воспользовавшись поиском в нацкорпусе, я обнаружил что как правило в такой конструкции деепричастие относится к следующему за ним глаголу, а не к предыдущему:

> Работали мы дружно, и **в результате, сделав** два или три варианта,
>   родили на бумаге киносочинение,

.

> меня отправили на медкомиссию и **в результате признав** психически здоровым ― перевели в другую часть

Оно и понятно здесь после "союза" **в результате чего**  должно следовать некое утверждение-предложение, а как известно предложения не могут состоять из  деепричастия без глагола.

Но все же нашелся единственный пример где это не так:

> он так и не смог уже больше его опередить, **в результате выпав** из призовой тройки.

Ну и полагая что всегда возможно заменить **в результате** на **в результате чего** получаем еще и такое

> он так и не смог уже больше его опередить, **в результате чего выпав** из призовой тройки.

Корректны ли грамматически эти два последних примера из нацкорпуса?

Comment: Зря вы удалили свой последний комментарий - с "пришли, в результате уйдя". Он очень в тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заглянем в словарь Кузнецова:

> **В результате *чего*, в зн. предлога.** Вследствие чего-л., из-за чего-л.
>
> **В результате того что, в зн. союза.** Вследствие того что, из-за того что.
>
> **И в результате, в зн. союза.** И потому, и вследствие этого.

Первые два не подходят по смыслу, потому что в примерах сначала идёт причина, а потом следствие. Посмотрим на последний вариант.

Это правильное предложение (союз соединяет два глагола):

> Работали мы дружно, *и потому*, ..., родили на бумаге киносочинение

А это нет, потому что деепричастию не нужен союз для присоединения к глаголу:

> он так и не смог уже больше его опередить, *и потому* выпав из призовой тройки.

Грамматически правильные варианты, однако не очень осмысленные:

- не смог опередить, *из-за/в результате* выпадения
- не смог определить *в результате того, что* выпал
- не смог опередить, выпав из тройки (тут это просто обстоятельство, без причины)

Comment: Спасибо! Разрешили мои сомнения насчет того что союз соединяет два глагола, а не глагол с деепричастием. Я как раз исследую виды связи деепричастия и глагола. Обычно если стоит глагол + деепричастие (оба совершенные либо оба несовершенные) то действие деепричастия немного раньше по времени ну точно не позже. В вашем последнем примере (не смог выпав)  как раз демонстрируется обратная ситуация - сначала не смог, а потому выпав. Эта нестандартная(обратная) связь деепричастия с глаголом как причины и следствия, для меня необычна и всегда подозрительна. Хочется разобраться в этом

Comment: Как я уже говорил глагол + деепричастие обычно подразумевает совместное действие либо более раннее действие деепричастия. Но попадаются примеры где оно более позднее. Казалось бы в таких ситуациях чтобы уточнить характер связи и избежать двусмысленности (лошадь упала сломав ногу или сломав ногу она упала ?) можно было бы вставить уточняющий союз "в результате" но как мы видели он не работает, да и вообще никакого уточняющего слова не находится остается только говорить "не смог опередить, выпав из тройки" смиряясь с двусмысленностью фразы

Comment: @user190920 Мне кажется, вы делаете неверные выводы: "Он сидел, сложа руки," - действие одновременно, нам не важно, что он сделал сначала, сел или сложил. Я бы сказал, что в общем случае деепричастия не дают информации о причине и следствии: "Не смог победить, выпав из тройки" - это просто "Не победил и выпал".

Comment: . @homocomputeris, в примере "Он сидел, сложа руки," скорее наречие, а не деепричастие.

Comment: Грамматически, сложа - устаревшее деепричастие. Пусть будет "сложив" или "подняв".

Comment: Да, форма деепричастия, которая сегодня воспринимается как наречие.

Answer (score 2):

Последний пример (с двумя вариантами) не корректен.
Деепричастие так не используют. Оно должно примыкать к действию, а там оно выражает следствие из действия и, по сути, заменяет глагол "*выпал*". Получается действие, а потом деепричастие, обозначающее самостоятельное действие, происходящее после основного. Да и звучит ужасно.
К деепричастию, стоящему после глагола, можно добавить "*при этом*". Но не "*вследствие / в результате этого*".

Во втором примере пропущена запятая, открывающая деепричастный оборот. Из-за этого неясно, к чему точно относится "*в результате*".

С первым примером порядок.

Более универсальной проверкой будет замена на "*в результате этого*".

Answer (score 0):

> Ну и полагая что всегда возможно заменить **в результате** на **в результате
>   чего** получаем еще и такое

А вот нет. Не всегда. Именно в тех случаях, когда "в результате" грамматически относится к деепричастию и нельзя. Более обще, когда "в результате" является предлогом а не союзом замена на "в результате чего" невозможна. Таким образом, ваше последнее предложение грамматически некорректно. Рстальные - нормальны.

Comment: А у нас "в результате" это предлог? Я не знаю. @homocomputeris говорит что это союз. мнения разделились)

Answer (score 0):

Все предложенные варианты нуждаются в редактировании.

В словаре указана основная функция: **в результате чего, в зн. предлога.** Функции союза (три варианта) выводятся из этой основной функции подстановкой пропущенного местоимения, и таким образом можно сделать **проверку** правильности конструкции (то есть стиля, грамматики и смысла).

(1) *Работали мы дружно **и в результате (этого)**, **сделав два или три варианта**, родили на бумаге киносочинение.*  Союз *и в результате* относится ко второму глаголу.

(2) Меня отправили на медкомиссию **и в результате (этого)**, признав психически здоровым,  перевели в другую часть. Аналогичная конструкция.

(3) *Он так и не смог уже больше его опередить, выпав **в результате (этого)** из призовой тройки.* Это уже не союз, а предлог с пропущенным местоимением.

(4) *Он так и не смог уже больше его опередить, **в результате чего** выпал из призовой тройки.* Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным присоединительным. Функция предлога: вследствие чего.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104239/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).